# Stroke disappears when I hit command + J?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, stroke, pen-tool

I am trying to join two paths together but when I hit command + J the stroke disappears?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it does not disappear, but in fact gets covered with a white fill, probably because some other points in the shape also need to be joined to create a continuos line.

There are other unclosed segments in there and Illustrator treats those as separate, overlapping, objects filled with white.

Remove the white fill from everything and you're 100% sure to be able to see the strokes, join everything that you need to join, then put back the white fill.

Alternatively, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> which takes you into outline mode, which is a 'basic' view of your artwork with NO fills and NO strokes rendered. Fix the shape in outline mode, then switch back to a 'normal' view via <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The object might have a white fill applied to it, making it appear invisible.

You can change the view to *Outline view* in the view menu of illustrator (or by hitting command-Y) – this way you will see all of the existing paths without styling attributes like fill or strokes.

Comment: I tried to add a stroke and it appears in the stroke panel when I selected it to be black however I can't see it..maybe I am in some view weird view mode?

Comment: @user3413128 did you try to remove any fill colours?